# Access 2016 prevent double loading of data

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, record

**My Setup:**

I have a decently large table where each record should be all sales for a specific store for that day.

For example the records look roughly like:

Location | Date | Sales | etc.

Store 1 | 1/29/2018 | $20 | etc.

Store 2 | 1/29/2018 | $5 | etc.

Store 1 | 1/30/2018 | $25 | etc.

Store 2 | 1/30/2018 | $10 | etc.

In short you should NEVER have the same store on the same day more than once.

What's the best way to check this?  Can I do data validation on my records (i'm assuming no because my understanding is it won't check vs the loaded data), or do I need to write something in VBA (i'm currently using canned saved imports but if it's a must I can write something).

I have an automated daily append to the table, but occasionally things get messed up and stripping out a days worth of duplicate data manually is obviously not ideal.

Comment: Access can help you to detect those duplicates stores and days easily with the query assistant. Just design a "search for duplicates" query, using as criteria the fields you don't want to be repeated (in your question, I understand those fields are Location and Date)

Comment: Oh god that's so obvious in hindsight.  I suspected this was a process solution.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help. Hope it's the solution you need. If it is, let me know and I'll post it as answer and we close the question

Comment: Yeah it works.  Really just easier to handle by importing to a temp table and then using a query to check it for duplicates before loading as opposed to arcane data validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was:

> Access can help you to detect those duplicates stores and days easily
>   with the query assistant. Just design a "search for duplicates" query,
>   using as criteria the fields you don't want to be repeated (in your
>   question, I understand those fields are Location and Date

OP tried and said:

> Yeah it works. Really just easier to handle by importing to a temp
>   table and then using a query to check it for duplicates before loading
>   as opposed to arcane data validation rules

So OP could resolve the problem by importing the data to a temp table, and then using the "check for duplicates" query, before loading the data to non-temp tables.